# WPF custom title bar with Windows 11 caption buttons

Tags: c#, wpf

To edit non client area, I need to create my own title bar in my WPF app setting WindowStyle to none and non resizable. I have created my own caption button but it don't get the feel of Windows 11. When we hover mouse over middle button we can see a window snap option as seen in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IciUf.jpg)
Is there anyway to achieve this, I mean there should be, I even tried many nuget packages having custom Window, but I didn't got what I wanted.
All I want is to get a Window with System's default Window behavior but can have a Sliding panel from left which is even over title bar, somewhat [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qkVK.jpg) but I dont want to make title bar myself I want systems default.
Even if its custom made I want it perfectly same as System's Default Window
Its already in many Windows apps :- [Clock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZh87.png) ,[Mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBWgU.png), [Even Word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahkMc.png) .
In each of this apps left panel is over title bar and even preserving the system's default window behavior, Please Please Please tell me I have been looking for it from 2 months.

Nuget Package I tried : https://github.com/Kinnara/ModernWpf

code I tried:

```
<Window '''''default code ''''
        ''''''''''''''''''''''
        ''''''''''''''''''''''
        ''''''''''''''''''''''
        WindowStyle="None"
        ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <!--This created blank window with no title bar-->



    <Grid>
        <!--creating title bar-->

        <Grid  ''''' code so grid appear as title bar on top
                and we can drag too>
            <!--caption buttons-->
            <button ''''button with '-' and style as 
                        windows caption button and minizimes window
                        when clicked'''''''''''/>
            <button ''''button with 'square symbol' and style as 
                        windows caption button and maximize or restore window
                        when clicked'''''''''''/>
            <button ''''button with 'close symbol' and style as 
                        windows caption button and close window
                        when clicked'''''''''''/>
        </Grid>
           <!---
                rest of the code
                """"""""""""""""""
                """""""""""""""
                """"""""""""""""--->
    </Grid>                           
<Window/>
```

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/apply-rounded-corners#how-to-opt-in-to-rounded-corners

Comment: I cannot really understand what is being asked